# Should a question be reopened if another close reason now suits it better?

Tags: discussion, support, closed-questions, review-queue, reopen-request

I just came across [this question](https://askubuntu.com/review/reopen/580864) in the reopen view queue and I'm not sure what to do. The new edit means that the current close reason doesn't really completely suit it any more, a better one would be the one that goes something like `This issue went away`. So should I vote to reopen and then to close it with that close reason? Or should I just leave it be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two options.

1. To leave the question closed, since it is still not clear.
2. To reopen the question and add the OP's answer as a community wiki answer.

I vote for the second option, because this answer may have some value for someone who meets the same problem. It is unlikely though.

Comment: Other people voted to leave it closed, so it is reasonable too.

Comment: I would add "vote to delete"

Answer (score 6):

I'll never vote to re-open a question just to close it again with a different reason. That wastes the time of potentially 10 or more reviewers, to what benefit? <sub><sup>Unless I can band together four others to re-open and close quickly.</sup></sub> This, IMO, makes sense only when going from (any close reason) → duplicate, since none of the other reasons contribute anything to obtaining a solution, and ultimately don't add any benefits for anyone.

If you feel strongly enough about the close reason, flag for moderator attention, not that that's a guarantee for anything. For example, I flagged [How do I add myself into the sudoers group?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124166/how-do-i-add-myself-into-the-sudoers-group), since I think it's really a dupe of  [How do I add myself back as a sudo user?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70442/how-do-i-add-myself-back-as-a-sudo-user) - the flag was marked as helpful, but as can be seen, the question status hasn't changed.